# not function UPDATE mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am this code, not function UPDATE in the cod.
I can make it work?

```
SELECT
      activitati.tip,
      clienti.NUME_J,
      clienti.NUME_F,
      clienti.JUDET,    

FROM activitati

JOIN clienti ON clienti.ID = activitati.ID_CLIENT


WHERE activitati.TIP = "Livrare"
      AND LUNA_DATA_ACTIVITATE BETWEEN "1" AND "12"
      AND ANUL_DATA_ACTIVITATE = "2015"

UPDATE dotari
SET dotari.CANTITATE = '1'
WHERE dotari.CANTITATE = "0" OR dotari.CANTITATE = NULL
LIMIT 1000
;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the comma after this line `clienti.JUDET, `

Comment: Then add a `;` after this line `AND ANUL_DATA_ACTIVITATE = "2015";`

Comment: You cannot run 2 queries together like that they have to execute seperately

Comment: is not goot execute seperately, i change in all data base, not in query

Comment: Sorry but they are 2 seperate queries. The second query is not dependant upon the first. Run one and then the other

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you!